# Canonical Celery single file hello world

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, celery

I cannot seem to find a single file anywhere online that will run from start to finish with Celery and Python to demonstrate it so I tried to make one. For some reason this is not working, I am new to Celery. In `test_celery.py` I added the content below:

```
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Celery(
    'test_celery'
    ,broker= 'redis://localhost/0',
    backend='redis://localhost/1'
)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(2)
    return x + y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = add.delay(4, 4)
    print( result.get() )
```

Then I ran the redis server on localhost and at the console entered:

```
celery -A test_celery worker --loglevel=info
```

So, now the worker is listening and I try to run `python test_celery.py` thinking that I should see my wonderful 8 in the console output. In the log of the worker console, I see `[2015-01-02 16:53:08,807: INFO/MainProcess] Task test_celery.add[2c6b19c0-3a3f-45d2-8024-64e112fa3419] succeeded in 1.9970000002067536s: 8` which is as expected but the call to `result.get` hangs in the main program console.

I must be missing something basic here, if anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Your code works as expected for me (prints `8`), only I used `backend='amqp', broker='amqp://'` since I only have rabbitmq on my machine. So I suspect there is some issue with your redis setup. I don't have much exeprience with redis, but I recall using separate databases was discouraged.

Comment: Interestingly I tested this code on ubuntu in a virtual box and it works with both redis and amqp. It also works weather using different redis databases or the same. This must be a platform issue, I was originally testing on Windows 7. It may also be related to the quirky networking/DNS habits of my company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to simply set the result backend with the `app.conf.update` call rather than in the constructor of the `Celery` object.

I found the solution to this problem in [this post](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/897#issuecomment-57350929) of [this thread](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/897) on the Celery GitHub page. It remains an open issue (for now)

**Solution**

```
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Celery(
    'test_celery'
    ,broker= 'redis://localhost/0'
)

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost/1'
)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(2)
    return x + y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = add.delay(4, 4)
    print( result.get() )
```

Works as expected.

Comment: Message received on running the program above: `The 'CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND' setting is deprecated and scheduled for removal in version 6.0.0. Use the result_backend instead.`